# Multiplying polynomial coefficients

Tags: polynomials, convolution

Take:

> $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ to be integer polynomials, and then interpret them as sequences in the obvious way: i.e. you put the $i$th term to be the coefficient of $x^i$. Then you'll find that $u\ast v$ is the sequence representing the coefficients of $u(x)v(x)$!
>
> Example: $u(x)=x-2$, $v(x)=3x^2+x$. The sequences are:
>   $$
> \dots u_{-2}=u_{-1}=0;\  \ u_0=-2;\  \ u_1=1; \  \ u_2=u_3=\dots=0
> $$
>   $$
> \dots v_{-2}=v_{-1}=v_0=0;\  \ v_1=1;\  \ v_2=3;\  \ v_3=v_4=\dots=0
> $$
>
> The convoluted sequence is:
>
> $$
> \dots (v\ast u)_{-2}=(v\ast u)_{-1}=(v\ast u)_0=0;\  \ (v\ast u)_1=-2;\  \ (v\ast u)_2=-5;\  \ (v\ast u)_3=3;\  \ (v\ast u)_4=(v\ast u)_5=\dots=0
> $$
>
> And that turns out to be exactly the sequence for $u(x)v(x)=3x^3-5x^2-2x$.

Why is $ (v*u)_1=-2$?  We have $v_1=1$ and $u_1=1$, and $1*1=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $\ast$ denotes [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution), not multiplication. Therefore
$$\begin{align*}(u\ast v)_1&=\cdots+(u_1v_{1-1})+(u_0v_{1-0})+(u_{-1}v_{1-(-1)})+\cdots\\\\
&=\cdots+(1\cdot 0)+(-2\cdot 1)+(0\cdot 3)+\cdots\\\\
&=-2\end{align*}$$

Comment: Where can I find this rule in the first place? $$\begin{align*}(u\ast v)_1&=\cdots+(u_1v_{1-1})+(u_0v_{1-0})+(u_{-1}v_{1-(-1)})+\cdots\\\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That follows directly the definition of $\ast$ (look at the Wikipedia page I linked to),
$$(u\ast v)_n=\cdots+(u_1v_{n-1})+(u_0v_{n-0})+(u_{-1}v_{n-(-1)})+\cdots$$ Didn't your teacher / book mention what they intended the symbol "$\ast$" to mean anywhere?

Comment: yes, the wikipedia page does explain that "*" means convolution, but I can't find the $(u*v)_n$ trick there.. How is it called?

Comment: Let "$f$" represent "$u$", let "$g$" represent "$v$", and use the notation $a_n$ for a sequence instead of $a[n]$ as they do in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Please quote the article.

Comment: And is this (coefficient method) really the best way to solve the equation?

Comment: The exact section I linked to states that
$$(f * g)[n]\ \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}\ \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty f[m]\, g[n - m]$$
They are simply using different letters and different notation for sequences, as I just explained.

Comment: Also, this is ultimately exactly the same computation you would do any other way of multiplying two polynomials (the extra 0's on either side are irrelevant). Whatever you find easier is fine.

Comment: Always have done it this way: $$ (x-2)(3x^2+x)=3x^3+x^2-2*3x^2-2x= 3x^3+x^2-6x^2-2x= 3x^3-5x^2-2x $$.  Method above confused me.

Comment: What's the benefit of the method in the post above?